# Failed to load module script:MIME type error from server Expected javascript but got text/html

Tags: angular, routes, mime-types, page-refresh

In my angular app i have app-routing-module, in one of my componenet admin-home i have admin-home-routing-module, where i added other components as child routes. Everything works fine. But when i tried page refresh i got rthe following errors

Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec in main, runtime and polyfil js files and

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' in scripts js file

this is my admin-home routing module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'admin-home',
    component: AdminHomeComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthguardGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'client-home',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
      {
        path: 'client-home',
        component: ClientHomeComponent
      },
      {
        path:'configuration',
        component:ConfigurationComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthguardGuard]
      },
      {
        path:'user-signup',
        component:DetailsCollectorComponent
      },
      {
        path:'signup-second',
        component:SignupSecondComponent
      },
      {
        path:'confirm-otp',
        component: ConfirmOtpComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'date-selector',
        component: DateSelectorComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthguardGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'slot-selector',
        component: SlotSelectorComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthguardGuard]
      },
      {
        path:'slot-confirm',
        component: SlotConfirmComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthguardGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'confirmation-view',
        component: ConfirmationViewComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthguardGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'lane-allocation',
        component: LaneAllocationComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthguardGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'manager-create',
        component: ManagerCreateComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthguardGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'group-create',
        component: GroupCreateComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthguardGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'lane-create',
        component: LaneCreateComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthguardGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'share-app',
        component: ShareAppComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthguardGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'custom-fields',
        component: CustomFieldsComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthguardGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'custom-form-view',
        component: CustomFormViewComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthguardGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'customer-management',
        component: CustomerManagementComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthguardGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'group-lane-selector',
        component:GroupLaneSelectorComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthguardGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'custom-field-confirmation',
        component: CustomFieldConfirmationComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthguardGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'confirm-customfield-removal',
        component: ConfirmCustomfieldRemovalComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthguardGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'confirm-customfield-update',
        component: ConfirmCustomfieldUpdateComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthguardGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'error-page',
        component: ErrorPageComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthguardGuard]
      },{
        path:'confirm-delete',
        component:ConfirmDeleteComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthguardGuard]
      },
      {
        path:'confirm-slot-complete',
        component:ConfirmSlotCompleteComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthguardGuard]
      },
      {
        path:'confirm-lane-assign',
        component:ConfirmLaneAssignComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthguardGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'console-super',
        component: ConsoleSuperComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthguardGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'create-centers',
        component: CreateCentersComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthguardGuard]
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AdminHomeRoutingModule { }
```

everything works fine in local development server(ng serve) in ng build and deployed to my server the above given error happened. Give me a solution?

Comment: Using developer tools look at the request and response for the js file. `the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html"` this is going to be a http 404 not found response. i.e. either the url is wrong, or the url is right and the file doesn't exist.

Comment: the files exist and i cant find anything wrong with the url.